# Apple Crash Reporting service Delay

Tags: ios

I have gone through Apple Crash reporting service documentation which states that
"There may be upto a 3 day delay between when you first distribute your app and when the crash reports are available in Xcode ". But nothing specific was mentioned about the delay involved in collecting the logs from users and displaying in the Crashes organizer of Xcode. There was no information available online.what is the delay between the time app crashed in users device and report appearing in Xcode crash organizer?

Assumption : User allowed to upload the crash report.

Note : Apple doc also says, Crash reports are created daily. does that mean reports are available with a max delay of one day?

Comment: Any reference to the doc that states "There may be upto a 3 day delay between when you first distribute your app and when the crash reports are available in Xcode "?

Comment: @JohanKarlsson: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-crashes_organizer/AboutCrashesOrganizer/AboutCrashesOrganizer.html

Answer (score 0):

They mean that crash reports are created on a daily basis, so you might get it the next day, but also you might get it up to 3 days later.